# PHP - Laravel - Convert .docx to PDF format

Tags: php, laravel, docx, phpword, pdf-conversion

How can I convert a document (docx) to PDF format using PHP Laravel?

Before converting this, I'm using PHPWord for set variables, and after that, I want to save it or convert it to PDF.

Comment: As far as I know, LibreOffice is the only option, since it has great support for word files; I've done that in one of my side projects and maybe I'll open source it soon.

Answer (score 1):

#### Detailed Summary:

- **Initial Setup**: Begin by installing the required packages—`PHPWord` for DOCX manipulation and `Dompdf` for PDF conversion—using Composer.
- **DOCX Creation or Manipulation**: Utilize the `PHPWord` library to either create a new DOCX file or manipulate an existing one. Save this intermediate DOCX file.
- **DOCX to HTML Conversion**: Use `PHPWord` to convert the DOCX file into an HTML file, which will serve as an intermediate step before the PDF conversion.
- **HTML to PDF Conversion**: Utilize the `Dompdf` library to convert the intermediate HTML file to a PDF file. Save this PDF file.
- **Laravel Integration**: Integrate the entire process within a Laravel application by wrapping the code into a controller method and linking it to a route.

#### Step 1: Install Required Packages

First, make sure you have `PHPWord` installed. If not, you can install it via Composer:

```bash
composer require phpoffice/phpword
```

For PDF conversion, you can use `Dompdf`. Install it as well:

```bash
composer require dompdf/dompdf
```

#### Step 2: Create a DOCX File using PHPWord

Assuming you are already using PHPWord for `.docx` manipulation, you can create or load an existing `.docx` file like this:

```php
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;

$phpWord = new PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText('Hello, world!');

// Save DOCX file
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$writer->save('helloWorld.docx');
```

#### Step 3: Convert DOCX to PDF

Convert the `.docx` file to `.pdf` using `Dompdf`:

```php
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// Load .docx file content
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('helloWorld.docx');

// Save the document as HTML
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
$writer->save('helloWorld.html');

// Convert HTML to PDF using Dompdf
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml(file_get_contents('helloWorld.html'));

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();

// Save the PDF
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('helloWorld.pdf', $output);
```

#### Step 4: Integrate into Laravel

Wrap the above code inside a Laravel controller method:

```php
public function convertDocxToPdf()
{
// Your PHPWord and Dompdf code here
}
```

Then route a URL to this controller method.

---

### Critique and Suggestions for Improvement

- The conversion from `.docx` to `.html` might not be perfect for complex documents. For better accuracy, consider using `wkhtmltopdf`.
- This is a basic example; consider adding exception handling and validation for a more robust solution.
- Be cautious with confidential data and where you're saving the temporary `.html` and `.pdf` files. Secure the temporary location and delete files after use.

---

**Note: This solution is not fully tested and is provided as a guideline. Please test thoroughly before implementing in a production environment.**

Comment: I have tried with templateProcess on phpWord. It exports a perfect Word file and I tried to convert it to PDF and it works except the header and footer do not show in PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install unoconv on server.
Also, permission to run exec() is required on the server.

1. Install unoconv

> sudo apt-get install unoconv

2. add below line to convert desired docx file to pdf.

> exec("doc2pdf **sample-file.docx** **sample-file.pdf**");

Answer (score -1):

You can use the PHPWord library to read the contents of a .docx file, and then use another library such as Dompdf or mPDF to convert the contents to a .pdf file.
Here is an example:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$phpWord = IOFactory::load('path/to/file.docx');

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($phpWord->saveHTML());
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
```

You can also use the package like "phpoffice/phpword" and "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf"

```
composer require phpoffice/phpword
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

and then use them in the controller to convert docx to pdf

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;

$phpWord = new PhpWord();
$phpWord->loadTemplate('path/to/file.docx');

$pdf = PDF::loadView('view', compact('phpWord'))->save('path/to/file.pdf');
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the package like "phpoffice/phpword" and "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf"

```
  composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf  
  composer require phpoffice/phpword
```

Register Service Provider In config/app.php 
To register the service provider, open the config/app.php file. And add the following line in 'providers' array at the end:

```
'providers' => [
 .....
 Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
]
```

Also, add the following line to the 'aliases' array at the end. You can use any aliases as you want like we have used ‘PDF’ but you can also use aliases like ‘DoPDF’, ‘myPDF’, ‘PF’, etc

```
'aliases' => [
 .....
 'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
]
```

and then use them in the controller to convert docx to pdf

```
use PDF;
public function convertWordToPDF()
    {
            /* Set the PDF Engine Renderer Path */
        $domPdfPath = base_path('vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
        \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath);
        \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');
         
        //Load word file
        $Content = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load(public_path('result.docx')); 
 
        //Save it into PDF
        $PDFWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($Content,'PDF');
        $PDFWriter->save(public_path('new-result.pdf')); 
    }
```